# Access inner class from other class

Tags: java, sorting, inner-classes, comparator

I have this class having an inner class

```
public class A {
    public class NameComparator implements Comparator<A> {
        @Override
        public int compare(A o1, A o2) {
        return o1.name.compareToIgnoreCase(o2.name);
        }
    }
...
}
```

And I would like to access this NameComparator class from another class C (which resides in another package than A).

Example (from C):

> Collections.sort(aArrayList,A.new NameComparator());

This doesn't work. Should I move the inner class NameComparator so that it is not enclosed within the class A and rename it to something like ANameComparator? They are so closely related so it feels awkward to not put this functionality within the class A.

Comment: Make `NameComparator` a `static` class.

Comment: Or use an instance of A to create the instance of `NameComparator`.

Comment: you need an instance of a. `new A().new NameComparator()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use your code like this, you need to have the inner class static:

```
public class A {
    public static class NameComparator implements Comparator<A> {
        @Override
        public int compare(A o1, A o2) {
        return o1.name.compareToIgnoreCase(o2.name);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Why? Because if you don't mark the inner class static, it is only valid with an instance of the outer class.

You'll have to instantiate the comparator like this to use in zour use case:

```
Collections.sort(aArrayList,new A.NameComparator());
```

Comment: When I try this my compiler reports the following problem for class C:
Collections.sort(aArrayList,A.new NameComparator());

"A cannot be resolved to a variable".

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options.

Convert  your inner class into a static nested class

```
public static class NameComparator implements Comparator<A>
```

And in `C`

```
Collections.sort(aArrayList,new A.NameComparator());
```

Or if you don't want to modify inner class just create an instance of `A`.

```
Collections.sort(aArrayList,new A().new NameComparator());
```

Comment: The second alternative worked, but when trying the first alternative (static) which looks "better" I think, I got the error described in the comment to ppeterka below.

Comment: i wouldnt make an inner class public but it's a design decision, you have a syntax error, that's why didn't compile!

Comment: How would you solve it? An additional external class? How would you bundle the functionality in a reasonable way?

Comment: It depends, if your class `A` has only private fields without public accessors or package accesors then yes i will make a nested class, but perhaps with a util method that returns that comparator or something like that.. if you have `getters` then ,  yes i'll do in an external file.